# How to Overcome 415 Unsupported Media Type Without giving Content Type in Rest Client

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Guys, I have Rest Controller, that give the response when I give content-type=application/XML in the request header, but I can't give like, because I have to change all my code. so if any chances to overcome this problem.

**My Rest Client:**

```
@PostMapping(path = "/sample",  produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<ResourceCreation> createSampleRecord(
            @RequestBody SampleAgentPost sampleAgentPost,
            @RequestParam(required = true, name = "accountid") String accountId,
            @RequestParam(required = true, name = "applicationid") String applicationId) throws Exception, ServerError {
        return sampleCreateController.create(sampleAgentPost, accountId, applicationId);
    }
```

**Then I already Try This Configuration:**

```
@Configuration
public class DefaultContentResponse implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .favorPathExtension(false)
                .parameterName("mediaType")
                .ignoreAcceptHeader(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use interceptor on UI to add content-type in request header

Comment: thanks @Naveen But I want to handle API Itself. I don't want to push GUI Changes

Comment: Have you tried specifying `consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}` as well?

Comment: I tried @Andreas , But Only it is working if I give, request content-type in the header. otherwise not working.

Comment: The HTTP specification says that a client SHOULD specify `Content-Type` header if it knows it. A REST client would know, so I'd say the client is flawed when it doesn't, so you really should fix the source of the problem (the client). --- But [comment by Naveen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60369328/how-to-overcome-415-unsupported-media-type-without-giving-content-type-in-rest-c?noredirect=1#comment106791421_60369328) is correct. You can add an interceptor that detects missing `Content-Type` header, and then examine the content to auto-detect, e.g. `<` = XML, `{` or `[` = JSON.